# Unable to raise resolution of third monitor

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I have three external monitors hooked up to my DELL Latitude 5400 via a K20A dock that connects using USB 3. the two monitors that have a good resolution (DEL P2419H 1920x1080 & DELL E228WFP 1680 x 1050) are hooked up via HDMI & Display port and the third monitor ( DELL P2417H) is connected via Display port too. Is there any way I can increase the third monitor's resolution? The drivers have all been updated and our local support team gave up, hence I'm looking if anyone here may have some suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As with any other USB-C or Thunderbolt dock there are 3 factors to consider:

1. The hardware inside the dock must be able to drive 3 monitors at the desired resolutions. This may mean you can only connect them to the available connectors in a certain combination. Check the docks manual. (I did a quick Google and it seems possible with your dock.)
2. The laptop must supply sufficient bandwidth to the dock to drive all displays together. It makes a real difference if the laptop provides DisplayPort 1.2 or DisplayPort 1.3 via de USB-C connector to the dock. The K20A dock can receive both, but allows higher resolutions with DP1.3 coming from the laptop.
3. The GPU in de laptop must be able to drive the requested resolutions and there must be enough video-RAM available to do so. This is usually a problem with an embedded GPU in the CPU and (if I remember correctly) your Latitude 5400 uses a Intel CPU with embedded GPU. Depending on the exact model of CPU this combination of 3 screens may be too much at your required resolution.